# error at freeswitch.consoleLog("info", message:getHeader("from")); in freeswitch

Tags: perl, chat, freeswitch

i am trying to make script https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_sms   to get message header from freeswitch and reply them but it is not working

here is script

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl 
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use IO::Handle; 
    our $message;
    our $msg = $ARGV[1];
    my $msg_arg1 = (split ' ', $msg, 3)[0];
    my $share_reciver = (split ' ', $msg, 3)[1];
    my $shared_amount = (split ' ', $msg, 3)[2];
    freeswitch::consoleLog("ALERT", message:getHeader("from"));
```

and here chatplan

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <include>
 <context name="default">
         <extension name="demo">
             <condition field="to" expression="^(.*)$">
          <action application="perl" data="message.pl '${from}@s' '${_body}'"/>
        </condition>
        </extension>
            </context>
    </include>
```

here is error
2014-03-20 11:21:53.496377 [ERR] mod_perl.c:72 [require '/usr/local/freeswitch/scripts/message.pl';]
syntax error at /usr/local/freeswitch/scripts/message.pl line 10, near "message:"
Compilation failed in require at (eval 3) line 1.

author of the  https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_sms#Programming has asked to define interface 
i am new in perl how to define interface in perl
**how to solve this  ?**

Comment: You're mixing up programming languages.   You have `Lua` mixed with `perl`.  Find the correct code from `freeswitch` as there appear multiple language options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

message:getHeader("from") -> message::getHeader("from")

Comment: dear  @Pradeep  i have changed that line  but now this error is coming            `Undefined subroutine &message::getHeader called at       /usr/local/freeswitch/scripts/message.pl`